# python regex or something else

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a code with asking for errors on interfaces from my network switches. The output that I'm getting varies sometimes.

the output that i get from the switches in this format : (number changes from time to time)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXO47.png)

so i want to print from the output that i get **only line with end with number that grater then 0 like the line with start BAG16**

my code is going like that :

```
import re
kobi = '''
BAGG11             13917779236           10133016           16491979          64
BAGG15             30841323485           22747672           19201545           0
BAGG16                  811970                  0             811970           0
'''
err = re.findall (r'[BAGG]',kobi)

print(err)
```

Comment: I tested on JavaScript this the pattern: `/BAGG.+?(?:\s+(?:0*[1-9]\d*|\d*\.0*[1-9]\d*))$/mg`. The paterrn find line starts with BAGG and end with number higher than 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done without regex.

Try this:

```
kobi = '''
BAGG11             13917779236           10133016           16491979          64
BAGG15             30841323485           22747672           19201545           0
BAGG16                  811970                  0             811970           0
'''

lst = kobi.split()
lines = [lst[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)]

for line in lines:
    if int(line[-1]) > 0:
        print(' '.join(line))
```

Output:

```
BAGG11 13917779236 10133016 16491979 64
```

I've made some assumptions about your input:

- it's always five rows
- last row is a numerical value

Answer (score 0):

You might use a pattern to match BAGG and digits at the start and match a digit starting with 1-9 at the end.

```
^BAGG\d+[^\S\r\n].*[^\S\r\n][1-9]\d*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NECd8x/1)

If there should be 3 columns following, a bit more precise match could be using a quantifier `{3}` to match the number of "columns" in the middle.

```
^BAGG\d+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\d+){3}[^\S\r\n]+[1-9]\d*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of line
- `BAGG\d+` Match BAGG and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\S\r\n]+\d+` Match 1+ whitespace chars without a newline followed by 1+ digits
- `){3}` Close non capture group and repeat 3 times
- `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1+ whitespace chars without newlines
- `[1-9]\d*` Match a digit 1-9 followed by optional digits
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MhWmtH/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/H18dkH)

For example

```
import re

kobi = '''
BAGG11             13917779236           10133016           16491979          64
BAGG15             30841323485           22747672           19201545           0
BAGG16                  811970                  0             811970           0
'''
err = re.findall (r'^BAGG\d+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\d+){3}[^\S\r\n]+[1-9]\d*$', kobi, re.MULTILINE)

print(err)
```

Output

```
['BAGG11             13917779236           10133016           16491979          64']
```